# Image Resizing issue on KonvaJs Jquery Canvas

Tags: jquery, image, canvas, konvajs

I am facing an issue with image resizing on overlay image with background image using KonvaJs JQuery. I want to set the resizing only on image, not for entire image size. Please find the attached screenshot. That will help you to understand easily. I need you help to resolve the issue. [Resize KonvaJs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy0JN.jpg) I am expecting the result looks like this. [Expected KonvaJs Resize Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDTrd.jpg) [Overlay Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVa0r.png) [Background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he4wF.jpg) Canvas Image - [Canvas Resize Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0ENb.jpg)
 Thanks

I tried this code.

```
 // Create a Konva.js stage
        var stage = new Konva.Stage({
          container: 'canvas-container',
          width: 712,
          height: 575,
        });

        // Create a Konva.js layer
        var layer = new Konva.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);

        // Load the background image (non-resizable)
        var backgroundImg = new Image();
        backgroundImg.src = customBgImagePath;

        backgroundImg.onload = function () {
          var background = new Konva.Image({
            image: backgroundImg,
            width: 712,
            height: 575,
          });

          layer.add(background);

          // Load the overlay image (resizable)
          var overlayImg = new Image();
          overlayImg.src = removedBgImagePath;

          overlayImg.onload = function () {
            var overlay = new Konva.Image({
              image: overlayImg,
              x: stage.width() / 2 - overlayImg.width / 2, // Center horizontally
              y: stage.height() / 2 - overlayImg.height / 2, // Center vertically
              draggable: true, // Enable drag-and-drop
            });

            layer.add(overlay);
            stage.draw();

            // Create a Konva.js Transformer for resizing only the overlay image
            var tr = new Konva.Transformer({
              nodes: [overlay],
              //keepRatio: true,
              //ignoreStroke: true
            });

            tr.hide();
            layer.add(tr);

            // When the image is clicked
            overlay.on('click', function () {
              // Toggle the Transformer's visibility and interactivity
              tr.visible(!tr.visible());
              tr.enabled(tr.visible());
              layer.draw();
            });

            stage.on('click', function (event) {
              // Hide the Transformer if the user clicks anywhere else on the stage
              tr.visible(false);
              tr.enabled(false);
              layer.draw();
            });

            // Enable resizing for the overlay image
            tr.on('transform', function () {
              layer.batchDraw(); // Redraw the layer ,
            });

            /* dataURL = stage.toDataURL({ pixelRatio: 3 });*/
            layer.Draw();

            //// Redraw the canvas on drag, drop, and resize
            //overlay.on('dragmove', function () {
            //  layer.draw();
            //});

            //overlay.on('transform', function () {
            //  layer.draw();
            //});

          };
        };
```

Comment: Please provide the 2 images used in the code.

Comment: I updated the two images on description. 1. Overlay Image 2. Background Image @VanquishedWombat

Comment: Thanks - did not see that so have used other images as examples - see my answer below.

Comment: Just updated the answer code to make it cleaner and fix a propagation issue. Please mark the answer as correct if it helps.

Comment: ok - I have now reviewed the files you posted. The issue you say is that the blackboard image is loaded and the transformer appears oversized, so with a lot of empty space around the blackboard.  This is actually correct if you look at the blackboard image itself - there is extra space around it. The Konva transformer 'fits' to the size of the image. Since the blackboard image includes the transparent space around it, the transformer includes that transparent space. Solution is to remove the transparent space manually. Try it.

Comment: ok sure @VanquishedWombat

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I want to download the overlay Image with background image after resized the overlay image using konvajs jquery. Also, I need to change the background width and height size during the download click and keep the overlay image current resize size. could you please help me?

Comment: That's not how it works here in SO.  First, explain how you fixed your issue, then if you have a follow up ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Have updated your code to more modern JS (const instead of var) and moved the assignment of image src after the image onload handlers are declared which is good practice. Also removed unnecessary calls for stage.draw and layer.draw and batchDraw because these are all built-in to konva now. And removed use of transformer.visible - it is easier to manage the transformer.nodes() list.

There *was* a syntax error layer.Draw() - even when you needed this it was layer.draw().

Finally added cancelBubble on the click of the image. Without this the click propagates to the stage which complicates matters.

Summary - it works as it is. Did I misunderstand the problem?

```js
const customBgImagePath = 'https://assets.codepen.io/255591/bgsvg.svg'

const removedBgImagePath = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588899357441-7f613216191b?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2OTU2NTM2NDh8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=400"

// Create a Konva.js stage
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'canvas-container',
  width: 712,
  height: 575,
});

// Create a Konva.js layer
const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// Load the background image (non-resizable)
const backgroundImg = new Image();

backgroundImg.onload = function() {
  const background = new Konva.Image({
    image: backgroundImg,
    width: 712,
    height: 575,
  });

  layer.add(background);

  // Load the overlay image (resizable)
  const overlayImg = new Image();

  overlayImg.onload = function() {
    const overlay = new Konva.Image({
      image: overlayImg,
      x: stage.width() / 2 - overlayImg.width / 2, // Center horizontally
      y: stage.height() / 2 - overlayImg.height / 2, // Center vertically
      draggable: true, // Enable drag-and-drop
    });

    layer.add(overlay);
    stage.draw();

    // Create a Konva.js Transformer for resizing only the overlay image
    var tr = new Konva.Transformer({
      nodes: [overlay],
      keepRatio: true,
      ignoreStroke: true
    });

    //tr.hide();
    layer.add(tr);

    // When the image is clicked
    overlay.on('click', function(evt) {
      if (tr.nodes().length > 0) {
        tr.nodes([])
      } else {
        tr.nodes([overlay])
      }
      // cancel the event from bubbling to the layer and stage
      evt.cancelBubble = true;
    });

    stage.on('click', function(event) {
      tr.nodes([])
    });

  };

  // Set the src after declating the onload handler
  overlayImg.src = removedBgImagePath;

};

// Set the src after declating the onload handler
backgroundImg.src = customBgImagePath;
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- USE DEVELOPMENT VERSION -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@9.2.1/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>o</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="canvas-container"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This was very helpful to cleanup the unwanted codes but my problem is overlay image resizing issue. I updated the image here. Background Image - [https://i.stack.imgur.com/he4wF.jpg], Overlay Image - [https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVa0r.png], Canvas Resizing Image - [https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0ENb.jpg]